# What do I need to know to integrate any rational function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, rational-functions

My analysis book makes the following statement:

> Every rational function with real coefficients can be integrated in terms of
>
> - rational functions,
> - logarithm functions,
> - arctangent functions.

Does it mean that after polynomial division, partial fraction expansion, completing the square, substituting where needed, and knowing that

\begin{align} 
\\  \int \frac{dx}{(x-a)^n} &= -\frac{1}{n-1} \frac{1}{(x-a)^{n-1}} \ \ \ (n \neq 1)
\\  \int \frac{dx}{x-a} &= \log|x-a|
\\  \int \frac{dx}{x^2+1} &= \arctan x
\end{align}

one can  integrate *any* rational function?

Comment: In principle. In reality, you will often not be able to split the polynomials into irreducible factors.

Comment: You also need to be able to compute $$\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^n}$$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: @mrf: I saw this one in many materials, yet I didn't quite understand why should we pay special attention to the integral if it can be quickly reduced to the 1st case after substitution and partial integration?

Comment: @Leo If you know complex numbers you can do it even without arctangent... You can just reduce it to the first and second formula (always).

Answer (score 0):

You're in part right, as compared to [this page](http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/rational/rational.html). Yes, you need to know about polynomial division, but you also need to know about the degree of the numerator and the denominator, beacuse (and this comes from the link) the degree of the numerator and denominator determines what to do first. If the degree of the numerator is greater than that of the denominator, you do polynomial division, otherwise, you need to factor the denominator. Then you do partial fraction expansion (like you said). Yes, you may need to know the conditions you stated because the rational function could be of any of those forms.

This is the best thing I can say, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a very similar claim in my book's (Spivak's *Calclus*) solution manual. I think the following explanation is why you can find the integral of any rational functional (note: Spivak's book deals with $\mathbb R$, so the following comments are specific to polynomials whose coefficients are $\in \mathbb R$ and whose input is restricted to $\mathbb R$).

I will restrict my discussion to rational functions where the degree of the polynomial in the numerator is less than the degree of the polynomial in the denominator (note that if the degree of the numerator is greater than or equal to the degree of the denominator, then the fraction can be rewritten as some polynomial - possibly a constant - plus some new fraction where the degree of the numerator is less than the degree of the denominator...obviously, all polynomials can be easily integrated).

---

There are two theorems that Spivak provides (without proof here *or* in the book's text):

> **Theorem 1**: Every polynomial function $q(x)=x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0$ can be written as a product of the form: $q(x)=(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}\times\cdots\times(x-\alpha_k)^{r_k}\times(x^2+\beta_1 x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}\times\cdots\times(x^2+\beta_{\ell}x+\gamma_{\ell})^{s_{\ell}}$ where $r_1+\cdots+r_k+2(s_1+\cdots+s_{\ell})=m$

The results of the first theorem are ultimately used in the second theorem:

> **Theorem 2**: If $n \lt m$ and $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, $q(x)=x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0$, then $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ can be written as a sum of terms that take on one of the following three forms:

- $\frac{a}{(x-b)^k}$
- $\frac{a}{(x^2+bx+c)^k}$
- $\frac{ax+b}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}$

(The full version of the theorem is written much more precisely...and I will include this at the bottom of the post...but, for the purpose of my answer, the above 3 forms are satisfactory).

One by one, we will consider how to approach integrating these fractions. A useful formula is the following (which can be proven using integration by parts):

> $\displaystyle\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^n}dx=\frac{1}{2n-2}\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^{n-1}}+\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\int \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{n-1}}dx \quad (\dagger_1)$

---

**First Expression**

$\displaystyle\int \frac{a}{(x-b)^k}dx=a\int\frac{1}{(x-b)^k}dx$

We can perform $u$-substituion letting $u=x-b$, which gives us $a\int \frac{1}{u^k}du$. Of course, the integral of this is just $a \times\frac{1}{-k+1}\times u ^{-k+1}$ or $a\log(u)$ (depending on the value of $k$). Following the final substitution, we just have: $\frac{a}{-k+1}\frac{1}{(x-b)^{k-1}}$...or $a\log(x-b)$.

---

**Second Expression**

It is important to first see that the following expressions are all equivalent:

\begin{align} x^2+bx+c &= \left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2+\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)\\&=\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)\left[\frac{\left(x+\frac{b}{2}\right)^2}{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}+1\right] \\&=\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)\left[\left(\frac{x+\frac{b}{2}}{\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}\right)^2+1\right]\end{align}

As such, consider next that $\displaystyle \int\frac{a}{(x^2+bx+c)^k}=a\int \frac{1}{\left(\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)\left[\left(\frac{x+\frac{b}{2}}{\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}\right)^2+1\right]\right)^k}dx=\frac{a}{\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)^k}\int\frac{1}{\left[\left(\frac{x+\frac{b}{2}}{\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}\right)^2+1\right]^k}dx$

We can now perform a $u$-substitution letting $u=\frac{x+\frac{b}{2}}{\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}$. Consistent with the notation of the $u$-substitution method, we would then write that $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}dx \iff \sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}} du=dx $. We can therefore express our integral as:

$$\frac{a\cdot \sqrt{c-\frac{b^2}{4}}}{\left(c-\frac{b}{4}\right)^k} \int \frac{1}{\left(u^2+1\right)^k}du$$

You should notice that we can now apply our reduction formula $(\dagger_1)$ as many times as necessary (reduce it down to $\int \frac{1}{(u^2+1)^1}du$...which is just $\arctan(u)$). Substitute back in the appropriate value for $u$, and we are done.

---

**Third Expression**

To deal with expressions of the third form, consider the following:

If $g(x)=x^2+cx+d$, then $g'(x)=2x+c$. Compare $g'$ with the function $h(x)=ax+b$. We can describe $h$ in terms of $g'$ with the following trick:

$ax+b=\frac{\frac{2}{a}(ax+b)}{\frac{2}{a}}=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}\left(2x+\frac{2}{a}b\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}\left(2x+\frac{2}{a}b+(c-c)\right)=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}(2x+c)+\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}(\frac{2}{a}b-c)$...really, all this is saying is that one line ($2x+c$) can be made into another line ($ax+b$) through the action of scaling (changing the slope) and vertical translation. Using this trick, we can rewrite the third expression as:

\begin{align}\int\frac{ax+b}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}dx &= \int \frac{\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}(2x+c)+\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}(\frac{2}{a}b-c)}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}dx\\&=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}\int \frac{2x+c}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}dx+\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}(\frac{2}{a}b-c)\int \frac{1}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}dx\end{align}

For the integral on the left, perform the $u$-substitution $u=x^2+cx+d$...which, as alluded to earlier, would give us $du=(2x+c)dx$. Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}\int \frac{2x+c}{(x^2+cx+d)^k}dx=\frac{1}{\frac{2}{a}}\int \frac{1}{u^k}du$$

Of course, this integral has an established form that we previously referenced in the **First Expression** section. For the integral on the right, well...we have already addressed how to determine this integral in the **Second Expression** section.

All done!

---

> **Theorem 2**: If $n \lt m$ and $p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, $q(x)=x^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_0$, which, by *Theorem 1*, is equal to $(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}\times\cdots\times(x-\alpha_k)^{r_k}\times(x^2+\beta_1 x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}\times\cdots\times(x^2+\beta_{\ell}x+\gamma_{\ell})^{s_{\ell}}$, then $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ can be written as \begin{align}\left [\frac{a_{1,1}}{x-\alpha_1} +\cdots+\frac{a_{1,{r_1}}}{(x-\alpha_1)^{r_1}} \right] &+\cdots \\+\left[\frac{\alpha_{k,1}}{x-\alpha_k}+\cdots+\frac{\alpha_{k,r_k}}{(x-\alpha)^{r_k}}  \right] \\&+\left[\frac{b_{1,1}x+c_{1,1}}{x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1} +\cdots+\frac{b_{1,s_1}x+c_{1,s_1}}{(x^2+\beta_1x+\gamma_1)^{s_1}} \right]+\cdots \\+\left[\frac{b_{\ell,1}x+c_{\ell,1}}{x^2+\beta_{\ell}x+\gamma_1} +\cdots+\frac{b_{\ell,s_{\ell}}x+c_{\ell,s_{\ell}}}{(x^2+\beta_{\ell}x+\gamma_{\ell})^{s_{\ell}}} \right]\end{align}